# Inner function not affecting variable outside function

Tags: android, kotlin

So I am using AsyncHTTPClient to make a call and check if a user is authenticated. I have a Boolean "authenticated" to check if they are, and want to change its value inside the onSuccess, however the onSuccess does not seem to be affecting the value of authenticated outside and I am very confused as to why.

I can confirm that it does indeed go into the if statement, so the response i am getting is correct. I am new to Kotlin, however something similar in Java does work as I am now transitioning.

This is my code:

```
    fun authenticate(username: String, password: String): Boolean? {
        var params = RequestParams()
        params.put("username", username)
        params.put("password", password)
        var authenticated: Boolean? = null
        var a: Int = 1

        //Encrypt password and stuff

        restClient.get("/authenticate", params, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: kotlin.Array<out Header>?, response: JSONObject?) {
                if(response == null) {Log.d("no response", "404")}
                else if (response.get("success").toString() == "true") {
                    authenticated = true
                    a = a + 1
                    Log.d("authenticatedInside", a.toString())
                    Log.d("authenticatedInside", authenticated.toString())
                }
            }
        })

        Log.d("authenticated", a.toString())
        Log.d("authenticated", authenticated.toString())
        return authenticated
    }
```

AuthenticatedInside gives the right values.

a is just a test integer, the result here is a is still 1, authenticated is still null and it returns null as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `null` because `onSuccess` method is called asynchronously, what that means is that method isn't called before you try to access value of `authenticated` and as such it still isn't initialized.

One of the ways to fix this is to create another function for example:

```
fun onAuthenticateResult(authenticated : Boolean){
   // Write what you want to do with authenticated here
}
```

Then call that method from onSuccess method, of course this won't be called on UI thread so be careful not to directly modify any part of your UI inside this method.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it was Async stuff...what I DO have experience with lol